# apache htaccess url rewrite parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having issue to rewrite url
Before asking my question I need to explain my website
My website is wroten in pure php, with main index.php and includes folder with php(inc) files which are included depending the requested page

I have the hereunder url:
https://www.example.com/client/reset.html?token=NNKE7MD7Q1

And I want to pass the token to my php file which will check the parameter token
I wrote the hereunder rule but I have error 404

```
RewriteRule ^client/reset.html\?token=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /?page=reset?token=$1 [L]
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^client/reset.html /index.php?page=reset [QSA,L]
```

you can use the QSA to append to query string